# After installing CyanogenMod 12+ fastboot is not working

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-2, fastboot, heimdall

I installed CyanogenMode 12+ in my S2 device. Every thing was working fine and I used fastboot to flash the ROM.

After installing CM when I go to download mode again, fastboot didn't detect the device. If I use heimdall it detect the device and also print the PIT information.

Now I am trying to flash ubuntu-touch on my device which requires fastboot to detect the device. How can I make fastboot working?

Comment: Which platform are you on? Windows? If so, then check your device driver via Device Manager and report back.

Comment: I am on Linux (Ubuntu 15.04)

Comment: It is a device driver problem on your PC and causes to Fastboot works normally but does not work in recovery,download mode.

Comment: How can device driver problem occur on Linux? What I had read that USB device drivers are native to windows only.